# Google Scripts If filename contains x string log "x was found" missing bracket?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm attempting to search through all of my files and see if any of the files have a specified string inside of their filename. The script will then return that X file was found. Later on, I hope to use indexOf to return "x file was found at position y in array"

```
function myFunction() {

  var response = "Current"
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   Logger.log(file.getName());

if(file.toString().indexOf(response)){
   Logger.log("the file" + file + "has been found at" response)};
}
```

When I run the program I receive the error message that I'm missing a ')' at the end of the last line. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a + in the last log, the compiler looks for the end of argument, while it actually continues.
Your code:

```
Logger.log("the file" + file + "has been found at" response)};
```

Should be

```
Logger.log("the file" + file + "has been found at" + response)};
```

Answer (score 1):

**Format your code!** You're missing a bracket at the end, and a "+" in the string that you're attempting to concatenate.

```
function myFunction() {

    var response = "Current"
    var files = DriveApp.getFiles();

    while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        Logger.log(file.getName());

        if (file.toString().indexOf(response)) {
            Logger.log("the file" + file + "has been found at" + response)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's there, just not in the code section, look just under the code.

Comment: @Zero even with that one, he was still missing *another* one.